# undefined method for ActionMailer::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I had downgraded back to rails version 4.2.3 from 5 because i was having some issues, now if i try to start the server i keep getting this error in the terminal and the server won't run. How do i get rid of this error?

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionmailer-4.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:569:in `method_missing': undefined method `perform_caching=' for ActionMailer::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: the rails server is refusing to start because of that error, how do i get rid of it?

Comment: I don't know. Here's a few pointers. - Look for ActionMailer in your config folder, try commenting out related code. - compare your use of mailers to a Rails 4 app.  Delete the mailers, seriously, if you can boot the app without them, then reimplement from a rails 4 tutuorail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to comment out `#config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false` in development.rb